# In a Unit Test how to control (pause, resume) internal background Task of the object under test

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

To give the generic question some flesh I have the following simple class to write my results to e.g. file:

```
class ResultWriter
{
    private BlockingCollection<string> buffer;

    public ResultWriter(TextWriter writer, int bufferSize)
    {
        buffer = new BlockingCollection<string>(bufferSize);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                using (writer)
                {
                    foreach (string s in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    public long GetBufferConsumption()
    {
        return buffer.Count;
    }
}
```

Now I find it surprisingly hard to write a unit test for the GetBufferConsumption method.
I would like to test it more or less like this:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetBufferConsumptionTest()
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ResultWriter target = new ResultWriter(sw, 100);
    Assert.IsTrue(target.GetBufferConsumption() == 0);

    //here somehow pause the internal task

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
    {
        target.Add(i+"");
    }
    Assert.IsTrue(target.GetBufferConsumption() == 5, "Wrong result message");

    //here somehow resume the internal task

    //somehow wait for the task to consume all 5 items - not relevant for this question

    Assert.IsTrue(target.GetBufferConsumption() == 0, "Wrong result message2");
}
```

The problem is obviously that after adding one or two items the internal background task (lets call it **consumer**) starts consuming them and this yields buffer count kind of random.

Options I considered so far:

1. Leave this method untested - no, obviously I don't want to go this way :)
2. Extract the consumer as a separate class and then just pass a mock of it to my test - I don't like this idea as the consumer is conceptually SO internal to the ResultWriter class... I don't want to make unnatural changes to my code just for the sake of testing.
3. Use some TextWriter Mock instead of StringWriter that would block consumption as I want - this is not perfect too as the first moment I'm able to block consumer thread is line: `writer.WriteLine(s);` and this is already after line: `foreach (string s in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable())` which in fact already consumes the first item from my buffer. Now having a test that adds 5 items and then expects 4 just because of the above seems far from elegant.
4. Mock the ResultWriter class and modify the constructor to delay Task starting - I'm not convinced to mocking the object under test. I'd like to avoid this approach if possible.
5. Make the `buffer.Count` property somehow accessible to test and compare this with result of `GetBufferConsumption()` - except for need to fiddle around with visibility of the property which I don't like I would still need to stop consumer to make sure nothing is consumed between `GetBufferConsumption()` call and checking the `buffer.Count`.

Comment: A small suggestion unrelated to your question, but you should be using Assert.AreEqual for that type of test, rather than Assert.IsTrue.  When IsTrue fails, you only know that it wasn't true, whereas if you are expecting 5 and don't get five, the assertion error will tell you what you actually got.

Comment: I think making the task you spawn in ctor part of your writer's state would not hurt. Now you pretty much detach yourself from any control over it if I read your code correctly. You can probably promote it to property, that would give you level control in in unittest that you are asking for, with a small caveat: you will still have to postpone task, like you said